# Sorting a schedule to show activities for the day

Tags: python-3.x

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.4
#March 27th 2017
#Class

import time

class DayPlanner:
    def __init__(self):
        self.schedule = []

    def add(self, datetime, activity):
        tt = time.strptime(datetime, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
        self.schedule.append( [time.mktime(tt), activity] )

    def delete(self, datetime, activity):
        tt = time.mktime(time.strptime(datetime, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M'))
        print("\n")
        for i in range(len(self.schedule)):
            if activity == self.schedule[i][1] and tt == self.schedule[i][0]:
                print("[[Match Found]]")
                print("\n")
                del self.schedule[i]
                break

    def show(self):
        for i in sorted(self.schedule):
            print('{:s}  {:s}'.format(time.ctime(i[0]), i[1]) )
#-------

sched = DayPlanner()

while True:
    date = input('date and time? ')
    if date == '':
        break
    act = input('activity? ')
    sched.add(date, act)
print("\n")
sched.show()

print("\n")

while True:
    date = input('Which date and time should I delete? ')
    if date == '':
        break
    act = input('which activity should I delete? ')
    sched.delete(date,act)
print("\n")
print("New Schedule")
sched.show()

print("\n")
print("\n")

while True:
    date = input('Which Date should I show the schedule for?')
    if date == '':
        break
    print("\n")
    print("Schedule for the day")

    sched.show()
```

So, I have a good setup for adding and removing my entries, even though the time format is crazy when typing it all out.

To add to the schedule you need to type the exact format such as `2017-5-5 3:00`.

My main question is how would I format that last `sched.show` to only show the schedule of the day?

I know I would need to make changes to the `def show()`.

Should I create a new `def` and have it specifically show the day?

I am drawing a blank here and would love some help!

Answer (score 0):

```
def showday(self,day):
    for i in sorted(self.schedule):
        sec = i[0]
        tt1=time.localtime(sec)
        stt=time.strptime(day,'%Y-%m-%d')
        if stt.tm_year == tt1.tm_year and stt.tm_mon == tt1.tm_mon and stt.tm_mday == tt1.tm_mday:
            print(time.ctime(sec), i[1])
```

I used this def to fix my issue. My greatest resource was jupyter to find some help regarding time. I wont lie it took a bit but I got it all figured out and it works pretty well. Posting my solution for archive just in case someone else comes up with something similar.